# DHCP request timing out, suddenly

Tags: networking

On a work computer. No problems with connectivity until now. I was working diligently, when suddenly my computer seized up. I thought it was a graphics issue and rebooted. When I couldn't log in (but my colleagues could) I realized that I couldn't authenticate to the LDAP server. From there, I realized it was because my wired eth0 interface was not communicating with the network.

## IFCONFIG

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr f8:b1:56:a8:14:6b  
          inet6 addr: fe80::fab1:56ff:fea8:146b/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:10557 errors:0 dropped:11 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:881 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:1231403 (1.2 MB)  TX bytes:205674 (205.6 KB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:2543 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:2543 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:419097 (419.0 KB)  TX bytes:419097 (419.0 KB)
```

I checked the cable, and I checked the port with a different cable, and the IT guy's laptop. No problems there. He gave me a USB -> Ethernet adapter which I am currently using, but being USB it is not fast enough for the kind of data processing I do.

## SYSLOG

Checked syslogs from about the time it started failing:

`cat /var/log/syslog | grep eth0`

```
Jun 28 12:46:05 picasso kernel: [    0.526128] r8169 0000:03:00.0 eth0: RTL8168g/8111g at 0xffffc90000074000, f8:b1:56:a8:14:6b, XID 0c000800 IRQ 47
Jun 28 12:46:05 picasso kernel: [    0.526130] r8169 0000:03:00.0 eth0: jumbo features [frames: 9200 bytes, tx checksumming: ko]
Jun 28 12:46:05 picasso kernel: [    5.261935] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
Jun 28 12:46:10 picasso NetworkManager[1865]:    SCPlugin-Ifupdown: devices added (path: /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.2/0000:03:00.0/net/eth0, iface: eth0)
Jun 28 12:46:10 picasso NetworkManager[1865]:    SCPlugin-Ifupdown: device added (path: /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.2/0000:03:00.0/net/eth0, iface: eth0): no ifupdown configuration found.
Jun 28 12:46:10 picasso NetworkManager[1865]: <info> (eth0): carrier is OFF
Jun 28 12:46:10 picasso NetworkManager[1865]: <info> (eth0): new Ethernet device (driver: 'r8169' ifindex: 2)
Jun 28 12:46:10 picasso NetworkManager[1865]: <info> (eth0): exported as /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/0
Jun 28 12:46:10 picasso NetworkManager[1865]: <info> (eth0): now managed
Jun 28 12:46:10 picasso NetworkManager[1865]: <info> (eth0): device state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'managed') [10 20 2]
Jun 28 12:46:10 picasso NetworkManager[1865]: <info> (eth0): bringing up device.
Jun 28 12:46:11 picasso NetworkManager[1865]: <info> (eth0): preparing device.
Jun 28 12:46:11 picasso NetworkManager[1865]: <info> (eth0): deactivating device (reason 'managed') [2]
Jun 28 12:46:11 picasso NetworkManager[1865]: <info> Added default wired connection 'Wired connection 1' for /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.2/0000:03:00.0/net/eth0
Jun 28 12:46:11 picasso kernel: [   21.290817] r8169 0000:03:00.0 eth0: link down
Jun 28 12:46:11 picasso kernel: [   21.290839] r8169 0000:03:00.0 eth0: link down
Jun 28 12:46:11 picasso kernel: [   21.290855] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
Jun 28 12:46:11 picasso kernel: [   21.291021] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
Jun 28 12:46:13 picasso NetworkManager[1865]: <info> (eth0): carrier now ON (device state 20)
Jun 28 12:46:13 picasso NetworkManager[1865]: <info> (eth0): device state change: unavailable -> disconnected (reason 'carrier-changed') [20 30 40]
Jun 28 12:46:13 picasso NetworkManager[1865]: <info> Activation (eth0) starting connection 'Wired connection 1'
Jun 28 12:46:13 picasso NetworkManager[1865]: <info> (eth0): device state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none') [30 40 0]
Jun 28 12:46:13 picasso NetworkManager[1865]: <info> Activation (eth0) Stage 1 of 5 (Device Prepare) scheduled...
Jun 28 12:46:13 picasso NetworkManager[1865]: <info> Activation (eth0) Stage 1 of 5 (Device Prepare) started...
Jun 28 12:46:13 picasso NetworkManager[1865]: <info> Activation (eth0) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) scheduled...
Jun 28 12:46:13 picasso NetworkManager[1865]: <info> Activation (eth0) Stage 1 of 5 (Device Prepare) complete.
Jun 28 12:46:13 picasso NetworkManager[1865]: <info> Activation (eth0) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) starting...
Jun 28 12:46:13 picasso NetworkManager[1865]: <info> (eth0): device state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none') [40 50 0]
Jun 28 12:46:13 picasso NetworkManager[1865]: <info> Activation (eth0) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) successful.
Jun 28 12:46:13 picasso NetworkManager[1865]: <info> Activation (eth0) Stage 3 of 5 (IP Configure Start) scheduled.
Jun 28 12:46:13 picasso NetworkManager[1865]: <info> Activation (eth0) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) complete.
Jun 28 12:46:13 picasso NetworkManager[1865]: <info> Activation (eth0) Stage 3 of 5 (IP Configure Start) started...
Jun 28 12:46:13 picasso NetworkManager[1865]: <info> (eth0): device state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none') [50 70 0]
Jun 28 12:46:13 picasso NetworkManager[1865]: <info> Activation (eth0) Beginning DHCPv4 transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
Jun 28 12:46:13 picasso kernel: [   23.791505] r8169 0000:03:00.0 eth0: link up
Jun 28 12:46:13 picasso kernel: [   23.791512] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
Jun 28 12:46:13 picasso NetworkManager[1865]: <info> Activation (eth0) Beginning IP6 addrconf.
Jun 28 12:46:13 picasso NetworkManager[1865]: <info> Activation (eth0) Stage 3 of 5 (IP Configure Start) complete.
Jun 28 12:46:14 picasso NetworkManager[1865]: <info> (eth0): DHCPv4 state changed nbi -> preinit
Jun 28 12:46:14 picasso dhclient: Listening on LPF/eth0/f8:b1:56:a8:14:6b
Jun 28 12:46:14 picasso dhclient: Sending on   LPF/eth0/f8:b1:56:a8:14:6b
Jun 28 12:46:14 picasso dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 3
Jun 28 12:46:15 picasso avahi-daemon[1859]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface eth0.IPv6 with address fe80::fab1:56ff:fea8:146b.
Jun 28 12:46:15 picasso avahi-daemon[1859]: New relevant interface eth0.IPv6 for mDNS.
Jun 28 12:46:15 picasso avahi-daemon[1859]: Registering new address record for fe80::fab1:56ff:fea8:146b on eth0.*.
Jun 28 12:46:17 picasso dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 7
Jun 28 12:46:19 picasso dhclient: DHCPREQUEST of 10.30.64.53 on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67
Jun 28 12:46:22 picasso dhclient: DHCPREQUEST of 10.30.64.53 on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67
Jun 28 12:46:28 picasso dhclient: DHCPREQUEST of 10.30.64.53 on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67
Jun 28 12:46:34 picasso NetworkManager[1865]: <info> (eth0): IP6 addrconf timed out or failed.
Jun 28 12:46:34 picasso NetworkManager[1865]: <info> Activation (eth0) Stage 4 of 5 (IPv6 Configure Timeout) scheduled...
Jun 28 12:46:34 picasso NetworkManager[1865]: <info> Activation (eth0) Stage 4 of 5 (IPv6 Configure Timeout) started...
Jun 28 12:46:34 picasso NetworkManager[1865]: <info> Activation (eth0) Stage 4 of 5 (IPv6 Configure Timeout) complete.
Jun 28 12:46:34 picasso dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 3
Jun 28 12:46:37 picasso dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 5
Jun 28 12:46:38 picasso dhclient: DHCPREQUEST of 10.30.64.53 on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67
Jun 28 12:46:41 picasso dhclient: DHCPREQUEST of 10.30.64.53 on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67
Jun 28 12:46:44 picasso dhclient: DHCPREQUEST of 10.30.64.53 on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67
Jun 28 12:46:52 picasso dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 3
Jun 28 12:46:54 picasso dhclient: DHCPREQUEST of 10.30.64.53 on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67
Jun 28 12:46:57 picasso dhclient: DHCPREQUEST of 10.30.64.53 on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67
Jun 28 12:46:59 picasso NetworkManager[1865]: <warn> (eth0): DHCPv4 request timed out.
```

IT seems to think the ethernet adapter died, but it's at least being recognized.. What can I do to fix it?

## UPDATES

via IT:

> I can ping this computer from the Access and Distribution switches, but not outside its subnet.

He asked me to verify the default gateway, but Default route (I'm assuming it's the same thing) is already set to 10.30.64.1 according to the GUI network manager.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that

```
Jun 28 12:46:13 picasso NetworkManager[1865]: <info> (eth0): carrier now ON (device state 20)
```

and

```
Jun 28 12:46:13 picasso kernel: [   23.791505] r8169 0000:03:00.0 eth0: link up
Jun 28 12:46:13 picasso kernel: [   23.791512] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
```

show that your ethernet adapter is working, and has an electrical connection with the other end, and that the "carrier" signal is detected.

Sadly, you get no response from your `DHCP` packets.

```
Jun 28 12:46:14 picasso dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 3
```

These lines show that your system is trying to use the IP address `10.30.64.53`

```
Jun 28 12:46:19 picasso dhclient: DHCPREQUEST of 10.30.64.53 on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67
Jun 28 12:46:22 picasso dhclient: DHCPREQUEST of 10.30.64.53 on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67
Jun 28 12:46:28 picasso dhclient: DHCPREQUEST of 10.30.64.53 on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67
```

Are you sure that the corporate DHCP server recognizes your MAC address and that IP address? The MAC address you're using is:

```
Jun 28 12:46:14 picasso dhclient: Listening on LPF/eth0/f8:b1:56:a8:14:6b
#                                                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: Yea, the department IT guy has access to the NAC sentry and whitelisted my physical address, but it didn't fix it.

Comment: Stupid IT changed something. This was fixed by someone else.

Comment: I am in the exact same situation.. I didn't changed nothing on my work ubuntu laptop, but suddenly I can't connect to ethernet with the DHCPREQUEST timing out..

Comment: Run `wireshark` to watch individual packets, very informative.